Is the consensus amongst most post Kantian philosophers skepticism
I’m curious whether philosophical skepticism, the idea absolute truth is impossible, especially when dealing with grand metaphysical questions (eg god, the nature of being as infinite or finite, the mortality or immortality of the soul, idealism vs naturalism, whether we perceive the universe as it actually is or not etc.) is consensus among post Kantian philosophers?

It's hard to tell what any single, absolutely or full majority thinks without asking them. And the question does not clarify who is considered a philosopher for the scope of this question.

See PhilSurvey 2020 for which views are how popular among philosopers. Almost 80% hold to non-skeptical realism with regard to the external world.

@NotThatGuy I don’t believe skepticism and solipsism are necessarily the same

@Manoffaith You're welcome to look through there to see if you can find a question closer to what you're looking for. There aren't many other places that provide data about the views of philosophers.

Re. Non-skeptical realism. The idea that there is a real external reality but nobody knows what it is for sure. I'm sure there's a Monty Python joke there.

@ChrisDegnen If you see a rock, you could be sure that it's there long before you have any idea what material it consists of.

@NotThatGuy I have defo mistaken a not-rock for a rock before. In the real external reality it would be undetermined: neither rock nor not-rock. Much as aletheia is subject to two-fold concealment which obstructs rock identification.

@ChrisDegnen The analogy is not "is that a rock or not a rock", but rather "is that rock-like thing real or not real" (as in whether it exists in the external world, supposing the external world exists, because otherwise it wouldn't be an analogy, it would just be the exact same question as the original question).

@NotThatGuy This is getting a bit too postmodern for me.
